# Shrink balanced sets in topological vector space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Assume we have a topological locally convex vector space $X.$ Now, we have a set $U \subset X$ that is balanced and open. Moreover, we have some $x \in U.$ Then I was wondering whether we can assume that $\exists \delta>0: x \in (1-\delta)U$?
Somehow this seems to be quite an intuitive property, but I do not see it directly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove this, is this: since $X$ is a topological locally convex vector space, $x\in U$ and $U$ is open, there is a neighbourhood $V\ni x$ s.t:

- $V\subset X$,
- $V$ convex,
- $V-x$ is a balanced and absorvent neighbourhood of 0.

As $V-x$ is absorvent, there is $\lambda>0$ s.t. 
$$
x/2\in \lambda (V-x)
$$ 
hence $x, x\left(1+\frac{1}{2\lambda}\right)\in V$. Since $V$ is convex, $\left[x,x\left(1+\frac{1}{2\lambda}\right)\right]\subset V$. Hence, we conclude
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta \in \left(0,\frac{1}{2\lambda+1}\right) & \implies & 1<\frac{1}{1-\delta}<1+\frac{1}{2\lambda} \\
& \implies & \frac{x}{1-\delta}\in U\\
& \iff & x\in (1-\delta)U
\end{eqnarray}